# Android Studio Vector Asset: Error while parsing ****.svg- Not a proper SVG file

Tags: android, svg, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

When I try to import my SVG through Android Studio, I get this error:

`Error while parsing image.svg - Not a proper SVG file`

Where can I find more information about what actually went wrong? I've tried numerous SVG validators (W3C SVG validator).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to find out what the parse error is?

[image]

Comment: Can you please attach the svg here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG is not supported because of corrupted or some of the properties not supported in the Android studio. unfortunately there is no other options to resolve this. So use another supported svg images